# Como pasar a un fragment desde una activity con android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando mi aplicación y llegué a un punto donde necesito abrir un activity que tiene tabs desde otra activity mediante un botón.
Sería algo mas o menos así:

[image: Activity 1 desde donde quiero lanzar la activity con tabs]

[image: Activity con tabs]

Lo he intentado mediante intent pero no conseguí nada, y no he logrado encontrar ejemplos que me puedan servir de guía como para realizarlo.

Si alguno me puede guiar o me diga como se puede hacer, se lo agradecería mucho.

Adjunto código de MainActivity que tiene el botón:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button entrar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    entrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    entrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Inicio.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Mi Activity con Tabs que nombré inicio:

```
public class Inicio extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inicio);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return tab3;

            default:
                return null;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "TAB 1";
            case 1:
                return "TAB 2";
            case 2:
                return "TAB 3";

        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Ahora los Fragments (cada uno en un Activity separado, llamados Tab1.java etc...):

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


}

public class Tab2 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


}

public class Tab3 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_3, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.user.tabsfragment">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Inicio"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hola @flo te recomiendo poner el fragmento de tu codigo

Comment: Como comenta Ivan, agrega tu código por favor.

Comment: Mira en tu Activity inicio, el metodo setContentView pasa como parametro el mismo layout que tu MainActivity, puede que este sea tu problema y no la forma en que inicias tu activity que parece correcta

Comment: Hola flo, no debes agregar `[SOLUCIONADO]` o cualquiera de sus variantes al título de la pregunta, esto no está permitido. Si alguna respuesta de otro usuario (o una autorespuesta) solucionan tu problema debes [aceptarla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) en vez de hacer lo anterior. Esta es la forma que existe en SO (junto a la puntuación) de valorar la utilidad de una respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

```
07-20 18:05:17.371 3393-3393/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-20 18:05:17.371 3393-3393/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
07-20 18:05:17.564 3393-3393/com.example.user.tabsfragment W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.tabsfragment-2/lib/x86
07-20 18:05:17.585 3393-3393/com.example.user.tabsfragment I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-20 18:05:17.720 3393-3393/com.example.user.tabsfragment W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-20 18:05:17.834 3393-3421/com.example.user.tabsfragment I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-20 18:05:17.834 3393-3421/com.example.user.tabsfragment D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
07-20 18:05:17.834 3393-3421/com.example.user.tabsfragment W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-20 18:05:17.834 3393-3421/com.example.user.tabsfragment D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
07-20 18:05:28.852 3393-3393/com.example.user.tabsfragment D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-20 18:05:28.854 3393-3393/com.example.user.tabsfragment E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.user.tabsfragment, PID: 3393

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.tabsfragment/com.example.user.tabsfragment.Inicio}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:207)

at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)

at com.example.user.tabsfragment.Inicio.onCreate(Inicio.java:26)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Hola, logré solucionar el error quitando el Toolbar desde la TabsActivity ya que al ver mi log decía que habia un problema con mi action bar y el toolbar, lo borré y se solucionó el problema.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es únicamente lazar otra activity desde la que te encuentras bastaría con:

```
//  Clase MainActivity
public void llamarActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Siendo, **MainActivity** desde donde la quieres llamar y **TabsActivity** el nombre de la clase vinculada a la activity de las tabs.

Y este método lo debes llamar desde el botón en el XML de tu activity_main:

```
//  activity_main.xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/boton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:onClick="llamarActivity"/>
```

Con ello solucionas el llamado a la otra actividad. Saludos.